ATmega328P interfacing with 433MHz RF module behaving strangely
I am trying to control an LED using RF 433MHz signals using two atmega328p attached to 16MHz crystals. The RF transmitters and receivers I got from Amazon. The serial communication baud rate is 4800 (also tried with 9600).
On the transmitter side, I have connected the DAT line  of the RF module to PD1 (3rd pin). On the receiver side, I have connected one of the DO (pin 5) to PD0 (pin 2) of the atmega328p. The receiver has green (1), red (2) and blue (3) LEDs.

The transmitter program sends a signal every 4 seconds to toggle the red and green LEDs alternatively by sending a command. Example, at t0 it sends 0xC3 to turn red on and turn green off. Then at t1 it sends 0xD3 to turn red off and turn green on. Blue led turns of if the receiver receives a command but doesn't match 0xC3 and 0xD3.
The receiver receives some signals, but it's very unreliable in that the red and green lights toggle even between signal transmission when there isn't supposed to be any signalling. It is not external interference, because if I power off the transmitter, receiver stops toggling the LEDs.
My transmitter code:
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <util/setbaud.h>

#define LOCK_LED  PB1

#define LOCK   0xC3
#define UNLOCK 0xD3

static void usart_init(void)
{
    UBRR0H = UBRRH_VALUE;
    UBRR0L = UBRRL_VALUE;
    UCSR0B = (1 << TXEN0);
    UCSR0C = (1 << UCSZ01) | (1 << UCSZ00);

    _delay_ms(500);
}

static void usart_send(unsigned char data)
{
    while (!(UCSR0A & (1 << UDRE0)))
        ;
    UDR0 = data;
}

static inline void lock(void)
{
    usart_send(LOCK);
    PORTB |= (1 << LOCK_LED);
}

static inline void unlock(void)
{
    usart_send(UNLOCK);
    PORTB &= ~(1 << LOCK_LED);
}

int main(void)
{
    DDRB |= (1 << LOCK_LED);
    PORTB |= (1 << LOCK_LED);

    usart_init();

    for (;;) {
        _delay_ms(4000);
        lock();
        _delay_ms(4000);
        unlock();
    }

    return 0;
}

Receiver:
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <util/setbaud.h>

#define TEST_LED    PB1
#define LOCK_LED    PD6
#define UNLOCK_LED  PD7

#define LOCK   0xC3
#define UNLOCK 0xD3

static void usart_init(void)
{
    UBRR0H = UBRRH_VALUE;
    UBRR0L = UBRRL_VALUE;
    UCSR0B = (1 << RXEN0) | (1 << RXCIE0);
    UCSR0C = (1 << UCSZ01) | (1 << UCSZ00);
}

static unsigned char usart_recv(void)
{
    while((UCSR0A & (1 << RXC0)) == 0);
    return UDR0;
}

static void led_init(void)
{
    DDRB  |= (1 << TEST_LED);
    DDRD  |= (1 << LOCK_LED) | (1 << UNLOCK_LED);
}

int main(void)
{
    usart_init();
    led_init();

    _delay_ms(2000);

    sei();

    for (;;)
        ;

    return 0;
}

ISR(USART_RX_vect)
{
    unsigned char data;

    data = usart_recv();

    if(data == LOCK) {
        PORTD |= (1 << LOCK_LED);
        PORTD &= ~(1 << UNLOCK_LED);
    } else if (data == UNLOCK) {
        PORTD |= (1 << UNLOCK_LED);
        PORTD &= ~(1 << LOCK_LED);
    } else {
        PORTB ^= (1 << TEST_LED);
    }
}


Please provide data sheet links for the receiver and transmitter. Amazon links are just a waste of time.

I'd say the modules function like I would expect if you try to simply transfer UART data.
These modules usually do not work with long periods of high and low states, i.e. a lot of DC content. So for example 0x00 and 0xFF would be poor as there is little changes in data bits.
UART as a protocol is also poor. Both the transmitter and receiver may need a preamble, i.e. a start pattern for both the transmitter and receiver to start sending and receiver to see the signal and adjust the reception gain.
Only after that the data can be transferred.
Basically, it's not a transparent link for arbitrary data. Data must have some specific properties to end up through the link, and even then, it might be a good idea to include a checksum or CRC, and some sort of retransmission as the receiver cannot request for retransmission.
Sort of like early Ethernet packet.

@kovac, try using the Arduino IR remote control library
